# C - strsep() function with int error, return value is char*

Tags: c, strsep

I used strsep() in C code, but I got this error.

[image]

```
void    get_token()
{ 
    char    *token;
    char    *stringp;
    int n = 1;

    stringp = buf;

    while( stringp != NULL )
    {
            token = strsep(&stringp, "\t\n");
            switch(n) {
            case 1 : strcpy(label, token);
            case 2 : strcpy(opcode, token);
            case 3 : strcpy(operand, token);
            } n++;
    }
}
```

This is my code and I using strsep() like this. 
I don't know the error said int. strsep() return char* I think.

Comment: Are you forgetting to `#include <string.h>` perhaps?

Comment: buf is array(global)

Comment: I already added string.h

Comment: your image description says that it is not an error it is just a warning

Comment: the posted code does not compile for many different reasons.  Please post code that compiles, other than the indicated problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an implementation that does not declare `strsep()` in `<string.h>`.

Consequences are;

1. the compiler assumes `strsep()` returns `int` (hence the first warning)
2. the linker (`ld`) does not find a function named `strsep()` in libraries included in the link (hence error about `strsep()` being unresolved by `ld`).

The reason this occurs is that `strsep()` is not part of the standard C library.  You either need to obtain a library that contains it, or "roll your own" version of `strsep()`.

Comment: It doesn't work even I declared <string.h>So I made strsep() function.

Comment: Note: `strsep()` is _not_ a POSIX function.  It was first provided on BSD, AFAIK, and may now be available on some other platforms, such as Linux.

Comment: To make `strsep()` available through `strings.h` on Linux using GCC you want to `#define` `_BSD_SOURCE`. For you reference the Linux man-page here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html